# android:fitsSystemWindows="true" for fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have one activity in which i am adding removing fragments programatically in `FrameLayout` container.

If i keep `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` for activities it works as expected. But if i apply `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` in activity in shows for all fragments, instead i want to apply `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` inside fragment layout or programatically in fragment.

Anyone faced this?

My layout looks like below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I read this correctly you want a single activity to show various fragments either full screen (`fitsSystemWindows="false"`) or standard layout with status/action/nav bars visible and not obscuring the window content (`fitsSystemWindows="true"`).

It is possible to do this by setting separate `FrameLayout` containers within a single `RelativeLayout` that is itself full screen.

You can then select which container to load your fragment into depending whether it should be full or standard screen layout, but remembering to remove any fragment from and/or hide the other frame layout.

You will of course need to co-ordinate with system UI visibility to show/hide/overlay the action bar and status/nav bars but that's not in the scope of the question.  See the docs on [Managing the System UI](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/index.html) for that.

Here is an example of what I mean:

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/containerFullScreen"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="false" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/containerNormalScreen"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The first frame layout will fill the screen and the second will honour the insets for the status/action/nav bars.

Comment: I have tried this bug no luck. 

In my application i have my own navigation buttons like "Back'

Comment: I have tried this bug no luck. When i make android:fitsSystemWindows="false"  to main root layout and add android:fitsSystemWindows="true" to fragment container it has no impact.

Comment: In my application i have my own navigation buttons like "Back", "Next". So if user click on any edit text, system displays down arrow to dismiss the keyboard. 

if android:fitsSystemWindows="true"  then system shows down arrow below to my navigation bar.

if android:fitsSystemWindows="false"  then system shows down arrow on the navigation bar which looks like "Back button of my navigation bar is overlapped with device arrow button"

Comment: Sounds like you need to read the link to the guide to managing the system UI.  The behaviour you describe is what might be expected if you aren't properly handling system UI visibility changes and responding to the proper nav bar becoming visible.   Note that you can specify individual layouts within your fragment layouts to respect "fitsSystemWindows" too.  If you could share your XML code, I could maybe make some suggestions.